# Electric fields and potential

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

E = electric field
V = electrostatic potential
r = distance
' = derivative

1. E = - (V)'
     therefore if E increases V decreases
2. Also if r increases E decreases                                                      because  E=kq/r^2
3. From 1 & 2, if r increases then V increases
4. But V=kq/r, so if r increases V decreases

Why does the 3rd point contradict with the 4th ?

Comment: Statement 1 should read:
$E=-\frac{dV}{dr}$ therefore if $E$ increases **$\frac{dV}{dr}$** decreases.

Comment: @Farcher so if V' decreases it doesn't necessarily mean V decreases ? Could you explain ?

Comment: Explained below as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your fourth statement is incorrect. It should be:

$$ V(r) = - \frac{kQ}{r} $$

Note the minus sign, which you omitted. The minus sign means that as $r$ increases $V(r)$ increases because it becomes less negative.

Comment: The potential gradient becomes positive and the electric field is then also negative.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these two graphs:

[image]

The potential gradient is negative and gets less negative as $r$ increases.

So minus the potential gradient $=E$ gets less positive.

So it is your first statement which is misleading.